# Hair particles on the plane going wierd

Tags: particles, hair, properties

I am new to blender and I'm trying to learn stuff. Recently I learnt how to make the grass on a plane from particle settings from several youtube video references. And I tried to do it finally, Even though I did exactly as it was shown, my hair particles are not growing on the plane uniformly. Rather they are growing from one point in random directions.
[image: Here, Just like this.]
[image: And sometimes, like this.]

All my other settings are set to basic, I can't figure out the problem.
I would be really glad if someone helped me out here, Thank you.

Here is my blender file for reference,

[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Could you describe a bit more about the tutorial and where you're stuck? If you're just adding a particle system to a regular plane that is definitely unexpected behavior, but since it's only a plane it shouldn't be too much trouble to start again with a new file. What happens if you try again from scratch?

Comment: The same problem repeats even if I start fresh from scratch. @ChristopherBennett

Comment: Hmm... and all you're doing is deleting the cube, adding a plane, adding a particle system, and then selecting hair?

Comment: Yes, Thats all. @ChristopherBennett

Comment: I added my blend file @Chris

Comment: Your file appears perfectly normal when I open it on my PC which would suggest there is  a problem with your copy of blender, or that you possibly have an incompatible GPU, or need to update your graphics drivers.

Comment: So, Can I try reinstalling another version of Blender? @ChristopherBennett

Comment: Absolutely. Uninstall - download - re-install. (You might want to make backups of any saved files just in case).  What type of GPU do you have?

Comment: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000. @ChristopherBennett

Comment: Hmm. I think that's your problem there. Blender 2.8+ only supports (integrated) Intel GPU's for Haswell architecture or newer. Yours is for Ivy Bridge architecture (previous generation - no recent driver updates). TLDR - your GPU may not be supported by blender 2.8 and above. 2.79 will still work for you, but you won't have the EEVEE render engine and the GUI won't be as pretty, but most of the features are still there. Link is here for more info and a list of supported GPU's in 2.8+ - https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

Comment: That's the problem I guess, Thank you.